Questions about ParallelGC and Full GC behavior in long-running systems
I have a few concerns about ParallelGC and its behavior in long-running systems:

It seems that only Full GC can reclaim the old generation, implying that the old generation can only grow until a Full GC occurs.
Therefore, it appears that in a long-running system, using ParallelGC almost inevitably leads to Full GC.

Here are my specific questions:

What kind of latency can we typically expect from a Full GC when using ParallelGC?
If the latency is significant, does this mean that for most server-side applications, the unoptimized G1 in JDK8 might actually be a better choice than ParallelGC?
While ParallelGC allows controlling latency via MaxGCPauseMillis, it achieves this by adjusting the heap size and other parameters. If our heap size is fixed and cannot be resized, does this parameter actually become ineffective?

I am currently using G1 in JDK8, but I have learned that ParallelGC has advantages in non-server applications (such as computation or batch processing scenarios). I hope to address my concerns about using ParallelGC in server-side applications.

The crucial aspect of said “non-server applications (such as computation or batch processing scenarios)” is that latency doesn’t matter. That’s why a through-put optimized GC might have advantages in such scenarios. If latency matters to you, you obviously have a different scenario. So you ran in a circle and are now where you started. You learned something interesting but irrelevant to your scenario.

Thank you for your answer. My question is: for JDK8, the default collector is ParallelGC rather than G1. Should we manually choose G1 for server-side scenarios? I have not used ParallelGC in a production server environment, so I want to know how significant the latency caused by Full GC is to help me make an informed decision.

I always used G1GC under Java 8 even when latency didn’t matter, because it’s the only GC supporting String deduplication in Java 8. To me, the question was not, how big a problem the latency of a ParallelGC would be, but whether the theoretically lower throughput of G1GC is a concern. I never experienced any problem. In theory, a concurrent GC requires more memory than nonconcurrent GCs, but in most cases, the String deduplication of G1GC will more than compensate. So I’d still prefer G1GC.
